# Is it still possible to import csv into Adobe stock in 2023?

Tags: csv, adobe

I don't see that anymore :

https://helpx.adobe.com/stock/contributor/help/organize-with-csv-files.html

any help ? do you know where I can find some support from adobe ?

Any people interested to solve this ?

trying to upload csv into the adobe stock platform -> if you have any help it will appreciated.

let me know please

thx a lot !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.